# Symfony 5 - Dependent Expression validation: If one non-required field is filled, make another non-required into required

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Lets say I have 3 fields (`Shipping Address 1`, `Shipping Address 2` and `Shipping Address 3`). They are all **optional**!

```
/**
 * @var string|null
 * @Assert\Type(type="alnum")
 * @Assert\Length(min=1, max=50)
 */
protected string $shippingAddress1;

/**
 * @var string|null
 * @Assert\Type(type="alnum")
 * @Assert\Length(min=1, max=50)
 */
protected string $shippingAddress2;

/**
 * @var string|null
 * @Assert\Type(type="alnum")
 * @Assert\Length(min=1, max=50)
 */
protected string $shippingAddress3;
```

I have all the getters/setters.

How can I make **Shipping Address 1** to be required if some of Shipping Address 2 or Shipping Address 3 are filled?

So basically, how can I make one (optional) field to be required if another is filled with the expression lang in the Annotations?

Comment: You cannot do this with annotations/attributes only. You have to write a custom validator or separate the rules into different [validation `group`s](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) and apply groups at runtime based on input.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific business logic, I cant see how this can be done with the buildin validation annotations.

You could create your own validation annotation like this:

```
/**
 * @OrderValid
 */
class Order {
    protected string $shippingAddress1;

    protected string $shippingAddress2;

    protected string $shippingAddress3;
}

/**
 * @annotation
 */
class OrderValid extends Constraint {
    public string $message = "";
}

class OrderValidValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        if (!$constraint instanceof OrderValid) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, OrderValid ::class);
        }

        // the $value is the $order obj, do the validations below
    }
}
```

Check the documentation to more detailed explanation on how to do that:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html